# Using percentage values in ANOVA test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, logistic, anova, data-transformation, proportion

I have a number of values expressed as an index (the proportion of heart muscle cells in s-phase compared to the total population of heart muscle cells, calculated as (number of S-phase cells / total number of cells)*100
Is the arc sin transformation appropriate to use here before running an ANOVA test? Or is there a better way of analyzing these values?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the arc sin transformation (or any other transformation) for these data.  You have discrete proportions because you have a number of cells in s-phase out of a total possible number of cells.  These data are binomials.  You should use logistic regression as the appropriate model to conduct a test.